# Google.Cloud.Firestore not writing data to firestore emulator

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, emulation

I'm trying to write data from my local environment (running on iis on my machine) to my Google Firestore emulator. The code runs, doesn't throw an error BUT the data doesn't seem to be being written to the Firestore emulator.

Using firebase CLI tools v8.6.0
Google.Cloud.Firestore v2.1.0

```
    string project = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["firestore_projectid"];
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST", "localhost:8080");
    FirestoreDb db = new FirestoreDbBuilder
        {
            ProjectId = project,
            EmulatorDetection = Google.Api.Gax.EmulatorDetection.EmulatorOnly
              
        }.Build();

    var dto = await GetLiveStreamDto();

    DocumentReference docRef = db
        .Collection("Events")
        .Document("123456789")
         

    await docRef.SetAsync(dto, SetOptions.MergeAll);
```

Answer (score 5):

For those who are wondering I was able to connect to the emulator via provided code in the question. It is not clear in the Firestore C# documentation.

```
    string project = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["firestore_projectid"];
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST", "localhost:8080");
    FirestoreDb db = new FirestoreDbBuilder
        {
            ProjectId = project,
            EmulatorDetection = Google.Api.Gax.EmulatorDetection.EmulatorOnly
              
        }.Build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've adding this validation to determine the environment involved (dev or prod):

```
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST", "localhost:8080");
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(_ => new FirestoreProvider(
        new FirestoreDbBuilder
        {
            ProjectId = "your project id",
            EmulatorDetection = Google.Api.Gax.EmulatorDetection.EmulatorOnly
        }.Build()
        ));
}
else
{
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST", "");
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(_ => new FirestoreProvider(
       new FirestoreDbBuilder
       {
           ProjectId = "your project id",
           JsonCredentials = "your json config",
       }.Build()
       ));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it seems that c# is not supported by the firebase emulator. check here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite#feature-matrix

for admin sdk just Nodejs