# Issues working with Firestore emulator via Docker

Tags: c#, google-cloud-firestore, emulation, firebase-tools

I am running the Firestore emulator as a Docker container and facing two issues.
Here's the code I'm using:

```cs
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST", "localhost:8080");

var builder = new FirestoreDbBuilder
{
    ProjectId = "default",
    EmulatorDetection = EmulatorDetection.EmulatorOrProduction
};
var firestoreDb = builder.Build();
    
var col = firestoreDb.Collection("Cities");
var docRef = col.Document("YVR");
var result = await docRef.SetAsync(new City { Name = "Vancouver", Population = 675_000 });
var doc = await docRef.GetSnapshotAsync();
doc.Exists.Dump();

var document = firestoreDb.Collection("Cities").Document("YVR");
var snapshot = await document.GetSnapshotAsync();
snapshot.Exists.Dump();
var city = snapshot.ConvertTo<City>();
city.Dump();
```

City is defined as:

```cs
[FirestoreData]
public class City
{
    [FirestoreDocumentId]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [FirestoreProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    [FirestoreProperty]
    public int Population { get; set; }
}
```

**Question 1**

Without specifying `ProjectId`, I get an exception `ArgumentNullException`,
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'projectId'). Shouldn't a null value resolve to the emulator since the `FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` environment variable is provided?
[image]

And what project ID value should it be if working with the emulator?

**Question 2**

If I put a value for `ProjectId`, the code works, but using the emulator UI at the default URL `http://127.0.0.1:4000/firestore/data` doesn't show the document I'm adding.

Comment: Have you checked this [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63203732/google-cloud-firestore-not-writing-data-to-firestore-emulator) for connecting to emulator using `c#` and [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75939744/cant-write-to-firestore-emulator)

Comment: Yes, I've seen those two. Both are not applicable. In my case I **can** write and read, just don't see it in the emulator UI. Which, I suspect, has to do with the project ID. But GCP's documentation is so confusing I can't sort it out.

Comment: Can I check which emulator you're using? (All my personal experience is via `gcloud emulators firestore start` but that doesn't have a UI, so presumably you're using the one documented at https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite?)

Comment: That's the one, @JonSkeet. It comes as an NPM package, which we wrap in a Docker image. This is something I wish GCP would do themselves. And I think I've figured out what's the issue - it's very coupled to the ProjectId. So when building the image and running as a container, the project ID used in the code must match the one baked into the image. I will need to check if omitting the project ID from the image would allow having FirestoreDbBuilder created w/o ProjectID and let the emulator be used with different .NET projects. Hence why I wish the image would be provided by Google :)

Comment: @SeanFeldman: If you don't specify the ProjectId in the FirestoreDbBuilder, the library will (currently) try to determine it by contacting the GCP metadata server - that's probably not what you want in this case. We could *potentially* have a different defaulting approach when connecting to the emulator, but that's not something that's going to happen imminently.

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/11454

Comment: @SeanFeldman , After going through the above discussions, I believe you found solution/workaround for your issue. Can you post it as an answer for better community visibility ?

Comment: @SeanFeldman I have posted an answer with the above comments. Please feel free to update if anything is missing in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I’m posting this answer as community wiki for better community visibility.

As it's very coupled to the ProjectId. when building the image and running as a container, the project ID used in the code must match the one baked into the image.

As per discussion on the [`github issue`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/11454) you raised, current workaround is to:

> Using an environment variable in the `Docker` container (which can then be passed in when starting it). I assume the `Docker` image uses (or could use) the `--project` flag. If you take that from an environment variable, you could pass that in when starting the container, so you only need a single image which can work with any project. You'd still need to specify the same project ID in the .NET code, but at least you wouldn't need multiple images.

Comment: Roopa M, you're rushing with the answer here. This is not the answer I would provide based on the findings in several repos. And, as a user of the NPM emulator, this is not the type of guidance that would help me.

Comment: @Sean Feldman I apologize for my action,  can you provide your detailed solution as answer?

Comment: No need to apologize. Once GCP teams get back to me with specific information for a complete answer, I'll post it if it differs from yours. Otherwise, I'll accept yours.